# 250V 50A Wiring questions

Tags: wiring

I have a generator that's got a starting watts of 9400 and running watts of 7500.

Its got 2 outlets for 240V  One marked 14-50R, 50A 120/240V and L14-30R 30A 120/240V.
My main intention is to power the gas furnace, some lights and keep couple fridges running in a power outage.

I would need to install a 30A or 50A 240 V inlet socket in the garage but the run to my breaker panel in the basement in almost 65 ft.

My questions:

- Can I use the 30A generator outlet instead of the 50A outlet considering the cost of 65 ft of 6AWG vs 65 ft of 10AWG?
  Considering the fact that the generator needs be 20 ft from the house when running, I guess the 20 ft need be taken into account for the wire run length.
- Can I run conduit on surface of garage wall to run the wire 10 or 6 gauge until it goes into the basement and then run the wire stapled to the ceiling joists till it reaches the breaker panel, or does the conduit need be run the whole length into the breaker panel?
  If so what type of conduit?
- What gauge wire should the extension cord from generator to inlet be?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: The 10 gauge should work, but you might find 8 or 6 gauge works better depending on the generator.  I had two generators 30 years ago, a very small honda about 1000w and a bigger one of 5000w.  That little honda could power stuff with only a small gauge extension.  The big one I needed short 10 gauge for a 15 amp well pump, when the honda powered it with a long extension that I think was 16 gauge(common cheap extension size).

Answer (score 1):

With that particular generator, the only benefit of using the 50A cord is access to the slightly higher "starting watts" - the running watts only add up to 30A. So if your usage is not demanding (seems correct) the 30A input is fine.

If choosing the 50A inlet, choose a CO-ALR rated inlet and use aluminum wiring, which might well get the cost down to the same level as the 10 AWG copper. Even though this generator does not actually produce 50A, if you put in a 50A inlet you need wiring that will be safe if someone does connect a 50A generator to it.

The extension cord needs to be the same ampacity as the outlet/inlet, which implies the same gauge for copper wiring. If the cord is copper and the fixed wiring is aluminum, the extension would be the same ampacity but probably smaller. For 30A on 10 AWG copper, it will be 10 AWG copper. The length is not enough to worry about upsizing it for voltage drop.

If using individual wires, they need to be in conduit the whole way.  If using or transitioning (*i.e.* at a junction box) to cable you can stop the conduit where it's no longer subject to damage.

Answer (score 1):

##### Don't Forget the Interlock

Not mentioned in the question, but extremely important is a **generator interlock**. This is basically a sliding piece of metal that fits around the main breaker and the generator inlet breaker such that only one can be on at a time. That prevents generator power from backfeeding to the utility and prevents utility power from zapping the generator. You still need to flip the breakers but this *forces* you to do so instead of relying on memory and checklists.

> *Can I use the 30A generator outlet instead of the 50A outlet considering the cost of 65 ft of 6AWG vs 65 ft of 10AWG?*

Yes. You must also use a 30A breaker for the inlet instead of 50A.

> *Considering the fact that the generator needs be 20 ft from the house when running, I guess the 20 ft need be taken into account for the wire run length.*

Correct. But 85' is not a big deal in terms of voltage drop.

> *Can I run conduit on surface of garage wall to run the wire 10 or 6 gauge until it goes into the basement and then run the wire stapled to the ceiling joists till it reaches the breaker panel, or does the conduit need be run the whole length into the breaker panel?*

You can switch between conduit and cable. Any place you use cable it makes sense to *not* use conduit (exception: if there is a short section that needs physical protection, you can use conduit for that). But also any place you use individual wires you *must* use conduit - you can't staple individual wires to the ceiling joists. But you can transition between conduit/wires and cable in a junction box, and with 10 AWG that is no big deal - standard wire nuts.

> *If so what type of conduit?

Whatever you want. The only catch is that certain types provide physical protection (may be needed in a garage because of cars) and certain types don't.

> *What gauge wire should the extension cord from generator to inlet be?*

10 AWG